# To evaluate integral using Beta function - Which substitution should i use?

Tags: real-analysis, beta-function

$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{m-1}(1-x)^{n-1}}{(a+bx)^{m+n}}dx = \frac{B(m,n)}{(a+b)^ma^n}$$

I have to use some kind of substitution but i do not understand what i use and why ?

Thanks

Comment: How do you define the Beta function?

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen It is standard definition, why?

Comment: there are different ways to represent functions like this.  Just making sure you don't  have a specific definition you have to use,  in case one of the answer uses a different one! Trust me,  it happens a LOT on this site that people get annoyed an answer used a different definition -_-

Comment: $$t=\frac{(a+b)x}{a+bx}$$

Comment: @Did Why will it work. How do you think about this ?

Comment: Did you at least try to see if it worked and how? Really zero personal input before receiving help and after receiving help...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's try the substitution

$$x=\frac{1-y}{1+cy}$$

so that $1-x=(1+c)\frac{y}{1+cy}$.

Then, when $x=0$, $y=1$ and when $x=1$, $y=0$.  We also have $dx=-(1+c)\frac{1}{(1+cy)^2}\,dy$.  Then, we can write

$$\begin{align}\int_0^1\frac{x^{m-1}(1-x)^{n-1}}{(a+bx)^{m+n}}\,dx&=\int_0^1 \frac{\left(\frac{1-y}{1+cy}\right)^{m-1}\left((1+c)\frac{y}{1+cy}\right)^{n-1}}{\left(a+b\frac{1-y}{1+cy}\right)^{m+n}}\,(1+c)\frac{1}{(1+cy)^2}\,dy\\\\
&=\frac{(1+c)^n}{(a+b)^{n+m}}\int_0^1\frac{y^{n-1}(1-y)^{m-1}}{\left(1-\frac{b-ac}{a+b}y\right)^{m+n}}
\end{align}$$

Choosing $c=b/a$, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{x^{m-1}(1-x)^{n-1}}{(a+bx)^{m+n}}\,dx&=\frac{1}{a^n(a+b)^m}\int_0^1 y^{n-1}(1-y)^{m-1}\,dy\\\\
&=\frac{1}{a^n(a+b)^m}B(m,n)
\end{align}$$

And we are done!

Comment: Please tell me how do i know which substitution to use here?

Comment: @TaylorTed You may use the one in this answer.  But since $B(m,n)=B(n,m)$, the one provided in the comment by Did also works.  That is, if one substitutes $y=1-t$, then the two substitutions lead to the same final result.  - Mark

Comment: In these type of questions is c = b/a always ?

Comment: @TaylorTed I'm not sure what is meant by "these types of questions."  There is no standard substitution for all problems.

Comment: @Dr.MV: [Do](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883077) you [realize](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/877460) what [you](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/691969) just [did](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/541135) ?

Comment: @Lucian Yes, I do.  The references embedded in your comment go beyond the exercise herein.  - Mark